How can I add external libraries to my jar file using IntelliJ Idea and Gradle?
I do have a Telegram Bot project in my IntelliJ Idea and it runs good inside IDE.
My goal was to build a jar file to test this app outside of my IDE.
After I build my jar file I always encounter same problem -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pengrad/telegrambot/TelegramBot

I use gradle so I do have this in build.gradle (not full list of libs):
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.github.pengrad:java-telegram-bot-api:5.0.1'
...
}

Then I go for Project Structure in IntelliJ -> Artifacts -> + sign -> jar -> from module with dependencies
Here is my last screen where as I believe I add dependency for java-telegram-bot-api...

My MANIFEST.MF file is:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Socrates


So my code works until place where it should use Telegram dependency
I tried to add Class-path to MANIFEST.MF - adding telegram package jar name there adds new issue - java can't find main module
Could you please help me to find right direction?

You could continue down this route of constructing an executable JAR by hand, or you can use the built-in Gradle method for pulling together an executable Java app, which is provided in the Application plugin.
First make sure this plugin is applied:
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

Make sure it knows about your main class:
application {
    mainClass = 'Socrates' // Use the fully qualified name
}

Then run the task installDist which installs your app in the build/install folder. This includes a JAR of your code and the dependency JARs, plus some scripts for execution. (See the Distribution plugin documentation, a plugin added by the Application plugin, for further details.)
The start-up scripts are in the build/install/applicationName/bin directory (replacing applicationName with your Gradle application name), one for Unix systems and one for Windows. These execute the java command with that main class name and a classpath pointing to the dependency JARs in the installation directory.
So for example on Unix, you can then run the command build/install/applicationName/bin/applicationName to run your app.
